# Second function isn't called in javascript using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm trying to make a simple live clock and a dd/mm/yy output on page,first function seems to work fine , but unfortunately the second function is not displaying on the page for some reason , tried everything but didn't helped. I would be grateful if you could help me. Thank you in advance

```js
setInterval(function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday ", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  var Part = (hour >= 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  if (hour == 0 && Part == 'PM') {
    if (minute == 0 && sec == 0) {
      hour = 12;
      Part = 'Noon'
    } else {
      hour = 12;
      Part = 'PM'
    }
  }
  if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
  }
  var curentday = ('<br></br>' + 'Today is: ' + daylist[day]);
  var time = ('Current time is : ' + hour + Part + ': ' + min + ': ' + sec + curentday);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
}, 1000);

setInterval(function display() {
  var date = new Date();
  var date = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var fullDate = ('Current date is :' + date + ':' + month + ':' + year);
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = fullDate;
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

#time {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20%;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is producing an error on the browser console.  Have you noticed and investigated that error?

Comment: `var date = date.getDate();` - you are _overwriting_ `date` here. After this line, it will contain a numeric value, not a `Date` instance any more. So you can not call Date methods on it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a modified version of the code, i changed "date" variable to "day" to be more explicit and i changed `getDate()` by `getDay()`

```
setInterval(function display(){
    var date = new Date();

        var day = date.getDay();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getFullYear();

  var fullDate =('Current date is :' + day + ':' + month + ':' + year );
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = fullDate;
}, 1000);
```

I think this what you looking for

Answer (score 1):

When you did `var date = date.getDate();` then you have overriden the value of `date` with a numeric value (date of month). Removing that line fixes the issue. I have also taken out the function definitions from inside the `setInterval` call to make it more readable and to ensure that they are called in the correct order, regardless of the Javascript implementations and versions. (I do not anticipate the callback of the second `setInterval` call to ever be called before the first, but it's always better to know that things work correctly rather than hoping and believing. Additionally, it's much more readable if we separate business logic from event handling)

```js
function display() {
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var fullDate = ('Current date is :' + date + ':' + month + ':' + year);
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = fullDate;
}

function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday ", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  var Part = (hour >= 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  if (hour == 0 && Part == 'PM') {
    if (minute == 0 && sec == 0) {
      hour = 12;
      Part = 'Noon'
    } else {
      hour = 12;
      Part = 'PM'
    }
  }
  if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
  }
  var curentday = ('<br></br>' + 'Today is: ' + daylist[day]);
  var time = ('Current time is : ' + hour + Part + ': ' + min + ': ' + sec + curentday);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
}

setInterval(function() {
  clock();
  display();
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

#time {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20%;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside @CBroe's answer on the fact that you're overriding the `date` variable, this is why it runs the first time - but 2nd time it uses the output from `date.getDate()`

```
setInterval(function display(){
    var date = new Date();
    var date = date.getDate();    <= this is where you override
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
```

I want to suggest a simpler way to describe time:

```
nd = new Date();

# 10/05/2023", you can format it
ns.toLocaleDateString([])

# "16:14", you can format it
nd.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do all those calculations. JavaScript has been improved and includes its own i18n (internationalization) library i.e. `Intl` which includes localization formatting.

```js
const
  timeEl = document.querySelector('#time'),
  dateEl = document.querySelector('#date'),
  locale = 'default'; // or 'en-US', etc...


update();
setInterval(update, 1000);

function update() {
  updateTimeDisplay();
  updateDateDisplay();
}

function updateTimeDisplay() {
  const
    now = new Date(),
    timeString = now.toLocaleTimeString(locale),
    weekday = now.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
  timeEl.innerHTML = `
    <div>Current time: ${timeString}</div>
    <div>Today is: ${weekday}</div>
  `;
}

function updateDateDisplay() {
  const
    now = new Date(),
    dateString = now.toLocaleDateString(locale);
  dateEl.innerHTML = `
    <div>Current date: ${dateString}</div>
  `;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#date, #time {
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="date"></div>
```